# Removing enclosed intervals in an array of intervals in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, intervals

I have such an array of intervals sorted by the lower bound ($a[$i] <= $a[$i+1] for every $i), key *l* is lower bound and , key *h* is upper bound and I'd like to remove all rows with intervals that are enclosed by larger intervals.

```
$a[0] = array('l' => 123, 'h'=>241);
$a[1] = array('l' => 250, 'h'=>360);
$a[2] = array('l' => 280, 'h'=>285);
$a[3] = array('l' => 310, 'h'=>310);
$a[4] = array('l' => 390, 'h'=>400);
```

So the result I'd like to get is

```
$a[0] = array('l' => 123, 'h'=>241);
$a[1] = array('l' => 250, 'h'=>360);
$a[2] = array('l' => 390, 'h'=>400);
```

This is what I attempted

```
function dup($a){
  $c = count($a)-1;
  for ($i = $c; $i > 0; $i --){
    while ($a[$i]['h'] <= $a[$i-1]['h']){
        unset($a[$i]);
    }
  }
$a = array_values($a);
}
```

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: I think you're just looking for array_unique ();

Comment: No, he wants to treat `l` and `h` as bounds on a range, and eliminate ranges that are enclosed by another (larger) range.  I'm curious what will happen with e.g. 5,15 vs 10,20.

Comment: nothing, because <10;20> isn't a subinterval of <5;15>

Comment: @pedmillon Do you have many intervals to compute ?

Comment: just few thousands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplistic approach, maybe not exactly what you want, but should at least point you in the right direction.  I can refine it if needed, just a bit busy and didn't want to leave the question unanswered..

```
$out = [];

foreach ($a as $valA)
{
  $found = false;

  foreach ($a as $valB)
  {
    if (($valA['l'] > $valB['l']) && ($valA['h'] < $valB['h']))
    {
      $found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (!$found)
  {
    $out[] = $valA;
  }
}
```

This is entirely untested, but should end up with only the unique (large) ranges in $out.  Overlaps as I mentioned in my comment are unhandled.

Comment: Because I have to leave and I'm just *that damn good*(tm).  Or not.  Downvote, edit, and repost if it doesn't work.

Comment: @firstone An untested but logically correct answer is better than no answer, at least if I was the OP, that's how I'd feel.

Comment: Looks good to me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2ccc87c9a10b3dd62aa43041f91f0fc2c983a9d4

Comment: @user3137702 `Overlaps as I mentioned in my comment are unhandled.` what? that's a pretty important part to the answer.

Comment: @user3137702 `Because I have to leave and I'm just *that damn good*(tm). Or not. Downvote, edit, and repost if it doesn't work.` this is such a lousy way to help people online

Answer (score 1):

The first answer which comes in mind was given with different variations by other contributors : for each interval, loop on each interval looking for a larger and enclosing interval. It's simple to understand and to write, and it works for sure.

This is basically n2 order, which means for n intervals we'll do n*n loop turns. There can be some tricks to optimize it :

- break'ing when we find an enclosing interval in the nested loop, as in user3137702's answer, because it's useless to continue if we find at least one enclosing interval
- avoiding looping on the same interval in the nested loop because we know an interval cant be strictly enclosed in itself (not significant)
- avoiding looping on already excluded intervals in the nested loop (can have a significant impact)
- looping on intervals (global loop) in ascending width = (h - l) order, because smaller intervals have more chance to be enclosed in others and the earliest we eliminate intervals, the more the next loop turns are effective (can be significant too in my opinion)
- searching for enclosing intervals (nested loop) in descending width order, because larger intervals have more chance to be enclosing other intervals (I think it can have a significant impact too)
- probably many other things that do not come to mind at the moment

Let me say now that :

- optimization does not matter much if we have only few intervals to compute from time to time, and currently accepted user3137702's answer does the trick
- to develop the suitable algorithm, it is necessary anyway to study the characteristics of the data that we have to deal with : in the case before us, how is the distribution of intervals ? Are there many enclosed intervals ? This can help to choose from the above list, the most useful tricks.

For educational purposes, I wondered if we could develop a different algorithm avoiding a n*n order which running time is necessarily very quickly deteriorated gradually as you increase the number of intervals to compute.

**"Virtual rule" algorithm**

I imagined this algorithm I called the "virtual rule".

- place starting and ending points of the intervals on a virtual rule
- run through the points along the rule in ascending order
- during the run, register open or not intervals
- when an interval starts and ends while another was opened before and is still open, we can say it is enclosed
- so when an interval ends, check if it was opened after one of the other currently open intervals and if it is strictly closed before this interval. If yes, it is enclosed !

I do not pretend this is the best solution. But we can assume this is faster than the basic method because, despite many tests to do during the loop, this is n order.

**Code example**

I wrote comments to make it as clear as possible.

```
<?php
    function removeEnclosedIntervals_VirtualRule($a, $debug = false)
    {
        $rule = array();

        // place one point on a virtual rule for each low or up bound, refering to the interval's index in $a
        // virtual rule has 2 levels because there can be more than one point for a value
        foreach($a as $i => $interval)
        {
            $rule[$interval['l']][] = array('l', $i);
            $rule[$interval['h']][] = array('h', $i);
        }

        // used in the foreach loop
        $open = array();
        $enclosed = array();

        // loop through the points on the ordered virtual rule
        ksort($rule);
        foreach($rule as $points)
        {
            // Will register open intervals
            // When an interval starts and ends while another was opened before and is still open, it is enclosed

            // starts
            foreach($points as $point)
                if($point[0] == 'l')
                    $open[$point[1]] = $point[1]; // register it as open

            // ends
            foreach($points as $point)
            {
                if($point[0] == 'h')
                {
                    unset($open[$point[1]]); // UNregister it as open

                    // was it opened after a still open interval ?
                    foreach($open as $i)
                    {
                        if($a[$i]['l'] < $a[$point[1]]['l'])
                        {
                            // it is enclosed.

                            // is it *strictly* enclosed ?
                            if($a[$i]['h'] > $a[$point[1]]['h'])
                            {
                                // so this interval is strictly enclosed
                                $enclosed[$point[1]] = $point[1];

                                if($debug)
                                    echo debugPhrase(
                                        $point[1], //           $iEnclosed
                                        $a[$point[1]]['l'], //  $lEnclosed
                                        $a[$point[1]]['h'], //  $hEnclosed

                                        $i, //                  $iLarger
                                        $a[$i]['l'], //         $lLarger
                                        $a[$i]['h'] //          $hLarger
                                    );

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // obviously
        foreach($enclosed as $i)
            unset($a[$i]);

        return $a;
    }
?>
```

**Benchmarking against basic method**

- It runs tests on randomly generated intervals
- basic method works without a doubt. Comparing results from the two methods allows me to predent the "VirtualRule" method works because as far as I tested, it returned the same results

  ```
  // * include removeEnclosingIntervals_VirtualRule function *

  // arbitrary range for intervals start and end
  // Note that it could be interesting to do benchmarking with different MIN and MAX values !
  define('MIN', 0);
  define('MAX', 500);

  // Benchmarking params
  define('TEST_MAX_NUMBER', 100000);
  define('TEST_BY_STEPS_OF', 100);

  // from http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php
  // used later for benchmarking purpose
  function microtime_float()
  {
      list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
      return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
  }

  function debugPhrase($iEnclosed, $lEnclosed, $hEnclosed, $iLarger, $lLarger, $hLarger)
  {
      return '('.$iEnclosed.')['.$lEnclosed.' ; '.$hEnclosed.'] is strictly enclosed at least in ('.$iLarger.')['.$lLarger.' ; '.$hLarger.']'.PHP_EOL;
  }

  // 2 foreach loops solution (based on user3137702's *damn good* work ;) and currently accepted answer)
  function removeEnclosedIntervals_Basic($a, $debug = false)
  {
      foreach ($a as $i => $valA)
      {
          $found = false;

          foreach ($a as $j => $valB)
          {
              if (($valA['l'] > $valB['l']) && ($valA['h'] < $valB['h']))
              {
                  $found = true;

                  if($debug)
                      echo debugPhrase(
                          $i, //                  $iEnclosed
                          $a[$i]['l'], //         $lEnclosed
                          $a[$i]['h'], //         $hEnclosed

                          $j, //                  $iLarger
                          $a[$j]['l'], //         $lLarger
                          $a[$j]['h'] //          $hLarger
                      );

                  break;
              }
          }

          if (!$found)
          {
              $out[$i] = $valA;
          }
      }

      return $out;
  }

  // runs a benchmark with $number intervals
  function runTest($number)
  {
      // Generating a random set of intervals with values between MIN and MAX
      $randomSet = array();
      for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
          // avoiding self-closing intervals
          $randomSet[] = array(
              'l' => ($l = mt_rand(MIN, MAX-2)),
              'h' => mt_rand($l+1, MAX)
          );

      /* running the two methods and comparing results and execution time */

      // Basic method
      $start = microtime_float();
      $Basic_result = removeEnclosedIntervals_Basic($randomSet);
      $end = microtime_float();
      $Basic_time = $end - $start;

      // VirtualRule
      $start = microtime_float();
      $VirtualRule_result = removeEnclosedIntervals_VirtualRule($randomSet);
      $end = microtime_float();
      $VirtualRule_time = $end - $start;

      // Basic method works for sure.
      // If results are the same, comparing execution time. If not, sh*t happened !
      if(md5(var_export($VirtualRule_result, true)) == md5(var_export($VirtualRule_result, true)))
          echo $number.';'.$Basic_time.';'.$VirtualRule_time.PHP_EOL;
      else
      {
          echo '/;/;/;Work harder, results are not the same ! Cant say anything !'.PHP_EOL;
          stop;
      }
  }

  // CSV header
  echo 'Number of intervals;Basic method exec time (s);VirtualRule method exec time (s)'.PHP_EOL;

  for($n=TEST_BY_STEPS_OF; $n<TEST_MAX_NUMBER; $n+=TEST_BY_STEPS_OF)
  {
      runTest($n);
      flush();
  }
  ```

**Results (for me)**

- As I thought, clearly different performances are obtained.
- I ran the tests on a Core i7 computer with PHP5 and on a (old) AMD Quad Core computer with PHP7. There are clear differences in performance between the two versions on my systems ! which in principle can be explained by the difference in PHP versions because the computer that is running PHP5 is much more powerful...

[image: PHP5]

[image: PHP7]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was missing break in the while cycle

```
function dup($a){
  $c = count($a)-1;
  for ($i = $c; $i > 0; $i --){
     while ($a[$i]['h'] <= $a[$i-1]['h']){
      unset($a[$i]);
      break; //here
     }
  }
  $a = array_values($a);
}
```

Comment: if array is like
$a[0] = array('l' => 310, 'h'=>310);
$a[1] = array('l' => 123, 'h'=>241);
$a[2] = array('l' => 250, 'h'=>360);
$a[3] = array('l' => 280, 'h'=>285);
$a[4] = array('l' => 390, 'h'=>400);

Then the above code may not work, also there are more complexity

Comment: array is sorted by the lower bound

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
function sort_by_low($item1,$item2){
    if($item1['l'] == $item2['l'])
        return 0;
    return ($item1['l']>$item2['l'])? -1:1;
}

usort($a,'sort_by_low');

for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++){
  for($j=$i+1; $j<count($a);$j++){
     if($a[$i][l]<=$a[$j]['l'] && $a[$i][h]>=$a[$j]['h']){
        unset($a[$j]);
     }
  }
}

$a=array_values($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code (Tested)

```
$result = array();
usort($a, function ($item1, $item2) {
    if ($item1['l'] == $item2['l']) return 0;
    return $item1['l'] < $item2['l'] ? -1 : 1;
});

foreach ($a as $element) {
    $exists = false;
    foreach ($result as $r) {
        if (($r['l'] < $element['l'] && $r['h'] > $element['h'])) {
            $exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$exists) {
        $result[] = $element;
    }
}
```

`$result` will contain the desired result